# WPF Drag and drop: how to distinguish Copy and Move operations on drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have working implementation of WPF DragAndDrop **Move**, when I start drag like this:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(sender, objToDrag, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

Then I want to add copy (e.g. pressing Ctrl key while dragging). If I press it with the code above, nothing changes. To enable Copy behaviour I modified code as follows:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(sender, objToDrag, DragDropEffects.Move | DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Now when I press Ctrl while dragging the mouse cursor becomes system defined copy cursor (arrow with '+' sign).

Then the question: how to distinguish copy from move on receiving end of the operation, where drop is handled?

The `DragEventArgs.Effects` field in `Drop` handler always equals to `DragDropEffects.Move | DragDropEffects.Copy` regardless whether the Ctrl button is pressed or not. It's strange, the `AllowedEffects` expectedly contains this combination, and I'd expect Effects to hold effective combination on moment of drop - but it's not the case.

Does it mean I should track Ctrl state myself? I hoped the OS/framework should hide such details.

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs(v=vs.110).aspx - There is an HowTo-example as well

Comment: I saw it but hoped there's better way. That's what I was afraid of, analyzing modifier keys myself. IMO that's what OS/framework is for. Well, that's reality.

Comment: Did you figure this out / write a bit of code that figures this out / you can share?

Comment: @ChuckSavage IIRC I implemented all the logic myself, tracked state etc., just what I hoped to avoid.